# Storing points in Koch fractal

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I'm asking today is to help with a Koch algorithm, to keep increasing the iterations on a line, without having to manually re-doing the process again and again. This is what I've got so far.

```
KochStar.prototype.draw = function (context) {

    var StartPoint = new Vector(this.getStart().getX(), this.getStart().getY());
    var MiddlePoint = new Vector(this.getMiddle().getX(), this.getMiddle().getY());
    var EndPoint = new Vector(this.getEnd().getX(), this.getEnd().getY());


    //iteration 1, left side
    var v1 = MiddlePoint.copy();
    v1.subtract(StartPoint);
    v1.divide(3);
    var P1 = StartPoint.copy();
    P1.add(v1);


    var v1R = v1.copy();
    v1R.rotate(-Math.PI/3);
    var P2 = P1.copy();
    P2.add(v1R);

    var v1R2 = v1.copy();
    v1R2.rotate(Math.PI/3);
    var P3 = P2.copy();
    P3.add(v1R2);
```

And what this is currently doing is taking a vector dividing it into three segments and rotating 2 of them by 60 Degrees to create the a triangle 'bump' on a simple straight line.

This is how I draw the line:

```
KochStar.prototype.draw = function(context) {

    context.save()
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth="5";
        context.strokeStyle="red";
        context.fillStyle = "Yellow";

        //iteration 1, left side
        context.lineTo(StartPoint.getX(), StartPoint.getY());
        context.lineTo(P1.getX(), P1.getY());
        context.lineTo(P2.getX(), P2.getY());
        context.lineTo(P3.getX(), P3.getY());  
        context.lineTo(MiddlePoint.getX(), MiddlePoint.getY());
        context.stroke(); 
        context.fill();
        context.restore();
    }
}
```

For what I'm asking is that for every time a start and an end point is called apply the math from earlier to automatically create the curve, and keep doing this for 'x' amount of iterations.

**--------------UPDATE----------------**

Okay so far what i've done is, which is going through the Arrays and doing each point. However What i really need it for an iteration part for example.  Start at A Go to B between A and B Do this: A[C-D-E]B like so.

What i need next is for something to take C-D from that Array and make those two points my Start and End and in between do the Math from earlier.

```
    KochStar.prototype.draw = function (context) {
        var pArrayX = new Array(P1.getX(), P2.getX(), P3.getX());
        var pArrayY = new Array(P1.getY(), P2.getY(), P3.getY());

        var p1ArrayX = new Array(P1a.getX(), P2a.getX(), P3a.getX());
        var p1ArrayY = new Array(P1a.getY(), P2a.getX(), P3a.getY());

        var p2ArrayX = new Array(P1b.getX(), P2b.getX(), P3b.getX());
        var p2ArrayY = new Array(P1b.getY(), P2b.getX(), P3b.getY());

        var iterat;

        context.save()
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = "5";
        context.strokeStyle = "red";
        context.fillStyle = "Yellow";


    context.lineTo(StartPoint.getX(),StartPoint.getY());
              for (var i = 0; i < pArrayX.length; i++) {
                 var x = pArrayX[i];
                 var y = pArrayY[i];
                 context.lineTo(x, y); 
             }  

        context.lineTo(MiddlePoint.getX(),MiddlePoint.getY()); 
             for (var p = 0; p < p1ArrayX.length; p++) {
                var x1 = p1ArrayX[p];
                var y1 = p1ArrayY[p];
                context.lineTo(x1, y1); 
            }     

        context.lineTo(EndPoint.getX(),EndPoint.getY())
            for (var z = 0; z < p2ArrayX.length; z++) {
                var x2 = p2ArrayX[z];
                var y2 = p2ArrayY[z];
                context.lineTo(x2, y2); 
            } 
    context.lineTo(StartPoint.getX(),StartPoint.getY())
```

Comment: Opps i posted without finishing the question! However the question i'm asking is how do i go about storing the points i've made into arrays and call them without having to do loads of lineTo. for Exmaple
lineTo(P1X, p1Y), lineTo(P2X, p2Y) Etc....

Comment: You can still edit the question. It looks like some code is missing too, if it's not a lot you should probably add it. Might also be a good time to cut down on code size, make some functions to handle that redundant-looking stuff

Comment: Okay thanks I'll re-work the question and re-post it ^^

Comment: no problem, it looks like an interesting problem, I'll try to take a look tomorrow (I'm sure someone else will get to it before then anyway)

Comment: Is there a reason you need the points, other than drawing them?  You can get the canvas context to do all the math for you in transformations, if all you need is to draw it.  If you need the points, have the `KochStar` constructor do all the math with a function that recursively "Koch-ifies" each successive pair of points in an array into an array of 4 points and concatenates them.  Keep the resulting array, iterate over it in `draw` with a call to `lineTo`.

Comment: Sqykly thats exactly what i need but i have no idea on how to go about it! I'm still trying to figure how do it xD